# Receive Axios response from POST

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, axios

I am trying to receive a response from my Node/Express server after making an Axios POST request.

I am able to successfully send a message to my server, where it is logged in console. I am trying to log the server response from my browser (using the code in axios.post.then() below). Any ideas why the response is not logging anything to the console?

-- client side --

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="axiosPost()">Post Test</button>

    <script>
        function axiosPost() {
            axios.post('http://localhost:3000/submitMessage', {
            message: "sample message",
            }).then(response => {
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        }
    </script>
    </div>
</body>     
</html>
```

-- server side --

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
var path = require('path');

// serves index.html
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/index.html'))
});

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening at http://localhost:${port}`))

// Parse JSON bodies (as sent by API clients)
app.use(express.json());

app.post('/submitMessage', function(request, response){
    message = request.body.message;
    console.log("Message: " + message);
    response.send('Server response message!!');
})
```

Comment: You've said what it **isn't** doing, but what **is** it doing? Does the `then` callback fire at all? Or is it the `catch` that does? Are any other messages displayed in the Console?

Comment: then does not fire at all. The only thing displayed in Console is: Listening at http://localhost:3000
Message: sample message

Comment: The **browser's** console, not Node's.

Comment: I didn't check before, but yes this is in the browser console: {data: "Server response message!!", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}

Comment: Well, that's the response object, and it is logging it, so what's the problem?

Comment: So it's all good then?

Comment: Well, the problem you described doesn't seem to exist.

Comment: I didn't realize it was logging to the browser console, I thought it should have been logging to the node console. I think this resolves my issue, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking back, my error was not realizing that there are two consoles: one for my client and one for the server. I was searching my server console for a message logged to my client console.

The message was ultimately being logged to my client console. Thanks to everyone who helped a beginner!

Answer (score 0):

listen to `response.data` in your front end. Or use simple `response.end('Message')` at your server side

Answer (score 0):

Well I've never used Axios, but I think you need to return JSON

```
app.post('/submitMessage', (request, response) => {
    message = request.body.message;
    console.log("Message: " + message);

    response.status(200).json({
        status: 200,
        ok: true,
        data: {
            msg: message
            // Any data for the response
        }
    })
})
```

You can also use Async/Await on the front-end

There's a nice post [here](https://dev.to/shoupn/javascript-fetch-api-and-using-asyncawait-47mp) you can checkout about it

Comment: Axios is quite capable of handling plain text responses. There's no need to encode it as JSON if all you are sending is a simple string.

Comment: Ok, but would it not be generally easier to manage client side with errors, etc...?

Comment: Not really. HTTP status codes can express error states. Either way, it doesn't solve the problem (which turned out to be "The OP was looking at the wrong console")